# how can we implement concurrency in ruby, where multiple thread are accessing same resource?

Tags: ruby, concurrency

I was asked to implement something like a movie seat booking with multiple concurrent request to book same seat. How can we do this in ruby without the use of database locks and only for in memory data structure? Are there other ways to have this type of check on application level?

Comment: Are you asking how to avoid race conditions? Most seat booking applications I have used these days put a temporary timed lock on a seat hold. E.g. I pick a seat and proceed then I have X minutes to complete the transaction or my seat is returned to the pool and I have to start over. Logically speaking this should not be difficult to implement.

Comment: yes, in race condition, let assume we have multiple request coming in to book same seat on the web application which is also running on multiple servers, how would i prevent that and avoid race condition without any transactions or without involvement of database?  just on application level.

Comment: You cant share state across multiple requests and multiple servers without involving the database in some fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Concurrency and parallelism aren't the same thing. You also can't do threading of writable shared resources without locking. It's pretty much axiomatic, because you don't want objects being mutated by multiple processes at once.

With Ruby, you have a few basic options:

1. For thread concurrency:

   - Use a thread-safe construct from a gem like the [concurrent-ruby](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby) project.
   - Use a class like [Thread::Mutex](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Thread/Mutex.html) to implement your own locking.
2. For parellel processing, [use a Ractor](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Ractor.html) if your version of Ruby supports it.

Solving these sorts of problems isn't impossible or hard. You simply have to account for the race conditions and possible mutability in your design.